# Как определить клик только по внутреннему элементу с одним классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, приветствую.
Только знакомлюсь с jQuery и столкнулся с примитивной задачей.
Как сделать так, чтобы при клике, событие было на внутреннем элементе, если классы совпадают с родителем.

```js
$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(1);
});
```

```css
.element {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
}
.el-parent {
  background-color: #444;
}

.el-child {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element el-parent">
  <div class="element el-child">
    click me
  </div>
</div>
```

Если кликнуть на внутренний элемент, то консоль возвращает 2 единицы. То есть клик на внешний элемент тоже срабатывает.
Пожалуйста, поясните, как правильно решить эту задачу(именно по классу элемент).
Заранее спасибо.
Всем хорошего дня =)

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` - предотвращает дальнейшее всплытие события. Тогда срабатывать будет только для нужного вам элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто задайте обработчик события вот так:

Изменяю ответ после разговора с автором.

```js
$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.element {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
}
.el-parent {
  background-color: #444;
}

.el-child {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element el-parent">
  <div class="element el-child">
    click me
  </div>
</div>
```

Вам просто нужно было блокировать [всплытие событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling), и для этого есть такие методы как `stopPropagation()` и `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Тогда при клике на внешний элемент, срабатывать обработчик события не будет. Так же если уровень вложенности будет больше, придется каждому указывать разные селекторы. Есть какое-то универсальное решение?

Comment: @ДанилСысоев вам нужен просто при клике посмотреть это внутренний или нет? или обработчик только на внутренний элемент?

Comment: @ДанилСысоев Изменил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, простите, а зачем тут `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan видимо я некорректно задал вопрос. Дело в том, что  для каждого блока будет отдельное всплывающее окно, и уровень вложенность может быть больше. И мне необходимо, чтобы данные выводились именно для того блока, по которому кликнули(для примера css свойство background-color)

Comment: По сути мне нужно просто исключить обработчик события для родителей с таким же классом.

Comment: @ДанилСысоев Понял и изменил ответ, вот посмотрите.

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо Вам большое=) А я пошел изучать как работает e.stopPropagation(); и e.preventDefault(); ;-)

Comment: @ДанилСысоев, изучение - это хорошо, но имейте ввиду, что в данном случае `e.preventDefault();` не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, хорошо, учту. Спасибо Вам.